# Determining if a Git repository contains a particular commit

Tags: git, commit, contains

I'd like to determine whether a remote git repository (origin) contains a particular commit.  My use case follows:

I'm preparing to create a public release.  I want to include the SHA-1 of the commit representing the pristine codebase from which I am building the release.

I also want to insure that the commit is not just a local commit, but that it has in fact been pushed to a central repository (origin).

I think

```
git pull --all & git branch --contains commit-hash
```

and then examining the output to see if it contains the current branch's tracking branch, works, but seems rather cumbersome.  I'm looking for something a little more succinct such as `git remote --contains origin commit-hash`, or `git cat-file origin commit-hash`.  I figure there has to be some plumbing command that Git uses when determining which objects need to be transferred during a push or pull - I'm just not familiar enough with the internals.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about: `git fetch && git branch -r --contains <commit-id>`

Comment: hmmm...  I had overlooked the -r option.  This would work, but I still think there has to be some plumbing command that I'm missing.  And really, I don't care whether or not the current branch's tracking branch contains the commit.  I just care that the commit exists in origin, without regard to what branch it's accessible from.

Comment: @Josh: Surely if this is a public release, you do care what branch it's on - it should be on the branch for that specific release.

Comment: As it is for a script, it's better to use the plumbing equivalent: `git merge-base --is-ancestor <commit-id> <remote_branch>`

Answer (score 5):

I may have overlooked some plumbing too, but as far as I can tell, the most direct way to test if commitA is an ancestor of commitB is to check if `git merge-base commitA commitB` is `commitA`. Fetch first, and then since they may be branches, use rev-parse to get an SHA1 for commitA:

```
if [ "$(git rev-parse $commitA)" == "$(git merge-base $commitA $commitB)" ]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

Wrap that up in an alias and you should be set.

As for during push and fetch (pull), those are implemented in C, so they're not directly calling any exposed plumbing commands.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` + `git branch -r` is the best you could get.

You can hack the [git protocol](http://git-scm.com/gitserver.txt) to give this result, but there are no plumbing you can use afaik. See section 5 for details. Just hack the "have" command and check if the server NAK.

A even easier hack is just try to push that commit, see if the server want it.

Answer (score 0):

can it be visible from the gerrit branch which is under review but not yet merged ?. after fetch , 
    git branch --all --contains 
will list all the branches but, commits on the review pages are not showed.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution `git fetch && branch -r --contains <commit-id>` to parse branches will solve the issue if any branch contains a commit.

It won't work if the task is to find the commit anywhere in the repo, for example, in hidden refs.

Since version [v2.33.0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60fadf8bd2abe6bede48bcf42377f6c8b7c1d0bb) git has documented `--negotiate-only` fetch argument to see, if the remote repository knows the commit. When the commit is known, it is in the command line output:

```
$ git fetch origin --negotiate-only --negotiation-tip=60fadf8bd2abe6bede48bcf42377f6c8b7c1d0bb
60fadf8bd2abe6bede48bcf42377f6c8b7c1d0bb
```

If I create a new commit, unknown for the server, here's the output for a usual and negotiate fetches:

```
$ git commit -m 'Empty commit' --allow-empty && git rev-parse HEAD
[master f14208fc92] Empty commit
f14208fc9259f8704bded1f7f80ac01dded55553

$ git fetch origin --negotiate-only --negotiation-tip=f14208fc9259f8704bded1f7f80ac01dded55553
e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920

$ git fetch origin f14208fc9259f8704bded1f7f80ac01dded55553
From github.com:git/git
 * branch                  f14208fc9259f8704bded1f7f80ac01dded55553 -> FETCH_HEAD
```